# CORS Error when Making a POST Request to Next.js 13.4.4 Endpoint

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cors, cross-domain, next.js13

I am using Next.js version 13.4.4 and have an endpoint at http://localhost:5000/logout. In my `src/app/logout/route.tsx` file, I have the following code:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  return new NextResponse("POST: /logout");
}
```

Now, I am trying to call this endpoint from another application running at http://localhost:3000. However, I keep encountering the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/logout' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

How can I resolve this CORS error and successfully make a POST request to the http://localhost:5000/logout endpoint in Next.js 13.4.4?

```
 const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/logout', {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      credentials: 'include',
  });
```

**My solution:**

I was able to fix the error by manually adding OPTIONS to my route.tsx and adding the headers listed below

```
export async function OPTIONS(request: NextRequest) {
    const origin = request.headers.get('origin')

    return new NextResponse(null, {
        status: 204,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': origin || '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization'
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**⚠️ There things to note about solving this issue in nextJS 13.**

1. Export the `OPTIONS` function in your `route.ts` handler file as shown below.
2. Make sure to remove the trialing `/` when making the fetch request in your code.
3. Modify your `next.config.js` file as below to update the headers on all responses.

**Solution Details And Code**

1. In order to fix it in `nextJs 13`, you have to export the `OPTIONS` async function in your routes handler as below in `app/api/route.ts` file.
   *(You can adjust it to allow requests from only specific origins but
   here I am allowing all origins.)*

```
// app/api/route.ts

  export async function OPTIONS(request: Request) {
  const allowedOrigin = request.headers.get("origin");
  const response = new NextResponse(null, {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": allowedOrigin || "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
        "Content-Type, Authorization, X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Date, X-Api-Version",
      "Access-Control-Max-Age": "86400",
    },
  });

  return response;
}
```

- Make sure to include just the HTTP methods that you will be supporting. The OPTIONS method must be included in the allowed HTTP methods since the browser will use it to determine whether to implement CORS protection or not. *In the above code I added all the HTTP methods except PATCH.*

2. Make sure you don't put a trailing slash when making the fetch request to your routes in your code. For example https://my-next-js-app.com/api/ is not the same as as https://my-next-js-app.com/api. If you include the trailing `/`, the server might send back a 308 redirect, but for some some reason the browser will also trigger a CORS error! Again, remove the trailing '/'when making the fetch request in your code.
3. Modify `next.config.js` as below

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // matching all API routes
        source: "/api/:path*",
        headers: [
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" },
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT",
          },
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            value:
              "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version",
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

Comment: 3. is similar 1. but for all requests. Why need 1.?

Comment: I was having this issue. I applied these changes, and it resolved the issue. I then un-applied the changes to see what specifically was the issue, and after reverting all the changes it still worked. 
This smells like Next.js not generating the OPTIONS endpoint automatically as specified here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route

Answer (score 0):

I THINK this is what you're asking for, not sure though. Gonna throw it in just in case though haha

This is what I have set up, I think it might work well in your case if you are trying to restrict the fetch methods:

In withMethods.ts (you can also have this in the same file)

```
import type { NextApiHandler, NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export function withMethods(methods: string[], handler: NextApiHandler) {
  return async function (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    if (!req.method || !methods.includes(req.method)) {
      return res.status(405).end();
    }

    return handler(req, res);
  };
}
```

In your API route file, in your case `src/app/logout/route.tsx`

```
import { NextRequest, NextAPIResponse } from "next/server";
import withMethods from "whereever you stored the file"

export async function ApiHandler(req: NextRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  return res.status(200).send("whatever you want to send");
}

export default withMethods(["POST", "GET", ...], ApiHandler)
```

Note: The withMethods code snippet is taken from Josh Tried Coding's youtube channel and from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lUkSgvmTYM&t=18068s&ab_channel=Joshtriedcoding) (highly recommend watching it)

Answer (score 0):

`cors` should be handled in middleware. if you know express, we install `cors`  package and register it in `app.js`. in nextjs13 you dont need to install this package

in next.js middleware file

```
const allowed=["enterallowedOriginsHere"]

// Request type is globally available
export function middleware(request:Request){
    // postman request do not have origin.
    // this code will allow requests from postman
    // If you do not want to allow postman requests, you can add logic to if condition
    const origin=request.headers.get("origin")
    if(origin && !allowed.includes(origin)){
         // return early
         return new NextResponse(null,{status:400,
                                       statusText:"BadRequest",
                                       headers:{'Content-Type':'text/plain'}})
   }
// add your logic based on different if conditions return different response
// finally 
return NextResponse.next()
}
```

then [from docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers#cors), you should alse set the headers in response inside route handlers. this is your route handler

```
export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
   const origin=request.headers.get("origin")
  return new NextResponse("POST: /logout",{
     headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': origin || '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization',
    },
   });
}
```

you can also view this [github discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/47933) for different options

Comment: Even though I added your code snippet to the middleware.tsx file and included "http://localhost:3000/" in the list of allowed origins, I am still encountering a CORS error when attempting to fetch data from http://localhost:3000. Despite taking these steps, the issue persists.

Comment: `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Thanks, somehow it was removed in the comments. I have entered it with http://, but works unfortunately still not

Comment: I think i know what is wrong. you have to set the headers in response of route files

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "add header to answer"?

Comment: Based on my observations, when making a POST request, it appears that an OPTIONS request is first sent. However, the OPTIONS request fails on my endpoint, causing subsequent requests to not be processed.
PS: I have added the headers

Comment: @hantoren add this `'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',` to response headers. updated the answer

Comment: I am starting to think that CORS is now set up well, but somehow next js is not trading an OPTIONS request. When I go into the network tab in my browser and examine the traffic, I see something like status 405 "method not allowed" and method OPTIONS. The same thing happens when I try to call my endpoint with postman and OPTIONS as method

Comment: do u have this in your middleare `return NextResponse.next()`

Comment: the solution was to add OPTIONS and all corresponding headers manually. I still don't know why nextjs doesn't provide these things automatically

Comment: I think nextjs 13 automatically handles options if you dont provide

Answer (score 0):

**Let's understand the issue :**

CORS is a protocol defining the way your server is handling the special requests.

**What is special request**

If the server thinks that the same user requested the API (or resource ) from multiple domain then we can call that a special request.

**How server is getting such requests ?**

1. If we are visiting multiple websites then our browser is saving all kind of data from session to cookies and other ..
2. If any of the website we are visiting, accidentally or purposefully requests the resource with our sessions and hit the server than what ?
3. Because other website have a different origin so server can see all such origin as cross origin.
4. It is obvious that such origins are requesting the server to share the resource from our details.
5. So it can be seen as cross origin resource sharing.
6. Server has mutiple methods to validate the orignal user request.

**Possible Solution to your problem :**

1. Set up a next.config.js  file and add source and destination

```
module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
       return [
         {
            source: '/api/:path*',
            destination: 'http://localhost:4000/:path*'
         }
      ]
  }
}
```

2. Use the library CORS (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) and tell the server to accept from your address by adding the following lines

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
}))
```

3. Add headers in next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/path/(.*)',
        "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" }, // Change this to specific domain for better security
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
          "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT"
        },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
          "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version"
        }
      ],
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

4. To use PUT and POST without CORS, add following lines in /api/index.js

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  const { method } = req;

  // This will allow OPTIONS request
  if (method === "OPTIONS") {
    return res.status(200).send("ok");
  }
};
```

**Still having some confusions**

You can visit

1. https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/headers
2. https://www.propelauth.com/post/avoiding-cors-issues-in-react-next-js