# in same VPS send POST request from NextJS to ROR app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, next.js, next.js13

In the same VPS, I have both a `Next.js` 13.4.12 and a `Ruby on Rails` application. I'm using Next.js as the frontend by consuming the RoR API endpoint. However, while I don't encounter any issues when making GET requests, I receive a 500 (Internal Server Error) when sending a POST request. This works locally but not on the server. But I tried to same post request with CURL it also works.

There is an issue with CORS, but I could not find it. Need help!

Thank you!

This GET request is working:

`const res = await fetch( "http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/v1/get_by_category/")...`

POST is not working

```
'use client'

import {useState} from "react";


export default function AddComment( { postId } ){

    const submitComment = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/v1/posts/${postId}/post_comments`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(form)
        }).then((res) => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                setFormSuccess(true)
                setFormSuccessMessage('Thank you for your comment! It will be shown after approved!')
            }
            resetForm()
        }).catch((err) => { 
            console.log(err)}
            );
    }
```

Error is:

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDogL.png)

there is no other error in nginx or backend log

working Curl request in server: (It means there is no issue on the backend side, because with curl request it populates the DB)

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"name": "asd","comment": "asd", "email": "asd@example.com"}' \
    http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/v1/posts/50/post_comments
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76347162/cors-error-when-making-a-post-request-to-next-js-13-4-4-endpoint